# Google OAuth Access tokens for different APIs

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I'm trying to access Reports API. And created source code for this on Java ([GitHub project](https://github.com/aldanchenko/gdrive-activity-report-downloader)).

I can get Access Token, but if I use it for Reports API Google always return me "Access denied. You are not authorized to read activity records" error.

I tried this Access Token to receive information from Drive API and it works. So Access Token is valid for Drive API and not valid for Reports API.

On this page I found this information - [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://github.com/aldanchenko/gdrive-activity-report-downloader)

> Access tokens are valid only for the set of operations and resources
>   described in the scope of the token request. For example, if an access
>   token is issued for the Google+ API, it does not grant access to the
>   Google Contacts API. You can, however, send that access token to the
>   Google+ API multiple times for similar operations.

So I can't use one Access token for all APIs? If so how can I get Access Token for Reports API?

I'm using Service Account JSON for access token generation.

Thank you for help!
Aleks.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your login code or a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  no one has time to go though your full project on GitHub to find the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I can't use one Access token for all APIs?

When you authncate a user you request some scopes this tells the user what apis and data you need access to.  There are a lot of [Scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes) each scopes gives you acccess to diffrent data.

> If so how can I get Access Token for Reports API?

You include the scope for that api in your authentication code.  Its hard to know which reports api you are talking about

- [adminreports_v1](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#adminreports_v1)

There is also the Google analytics reporting api,  and the Youtube analytics reports.  The easiest way to know what scope you need to include is to check the doucmentation page for the method you are using they will always include an auth section telling you which scope you need in order to use it.

Comment: I'm trying to use this Reports API - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive

Comment: Thank you DalmTo for help! I'm finally solve this issue. All configuration was right. Don't know why it need admin email as input parameter for JWT.